# Array subscript c++

Tags: c++

Что я делаю неправильно?
CodeBlocks говорит об ошибке:`invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript`,в строке с инструкциями `cfl=c[v][i]-f[v][i];`

```
int n, k, d, lim, t, cmmin = 1000, answ, g[100][100], c[100][100], f[100][100],
                     w[100], v, minFlow, v1, v2, s, i;

bool visited[100];
vector<int> put;

void where() {
  int f, cfl;

  vector<int> put;
  v = 0;
  while (!(v == n + d + 1)) {
    f = 0;
    visited[v] = true;
    put.push_back(v);
    for (int i = w[v]; i < n + d + 1; ++i) {
      cfl = c[v][i] - f[v][i];
      if ((!visited[i]) && (cfl > 0)) {
        v = i;
        w[v] = i;
        minFlow = min(cfl, minFlow);
        f = 1;
        break;
      }
      if (f == 0) {
        put.pop_back();
        v = put[put.size()];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: вы же переменной `int f,cfl;` f закрыли объявление массива `f[100][100]` переименуйте что-нибудь.

Comment: Школьный код,я только учусь и ни на что не претендую.

Comment: @gbg в школах так и учат. Если хотите компенсировать недостатки школьного образования — расскажите, как правильно делать.

Comment: @SpicyСlutches почти в каждой среде разработке есть автоформатирование кода. Очень рекомендую его использовать вообще в работе, а перед публикацией на SO - обязательно. Это проявление элементарного уважения к читающим вопрос, потому что неотформатированный код трудно читать.

Comment: @SpicyСlutches что касается переменных в одну строку — действительно, плохая практика. По-хорошему им ещё бы пригодились осмысленные имена. Так будет понятнее и не будет таких несуразных ошибок, когда случайно переиспользовали какую-то букву. )